# Delete/Replace multiple instances of two consecutive patterns using RegEx in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

Following is sample text.

```
Header
This is test, and
mid line adsf
bag a lot of many things
shoes>
shoes/
This line should not be affected.
Neither this line.
This is test, and
mid line
bag a lot of many things
shoes>
shoes/
Footer
```

Need to replace/remove lines where text starts with `This is test` and ends with

```
shoes>
shoes/
```

using Notepad++ 7.5

Newbie to RegEx, following were my trials, failed to select multiple instance.

```
(This is test).*(shoes/)
^This is test.*shoes/$
```

Expected output is

```
Header
This line should not be affected.
Neither this line.
Footer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^This is test((.|\n|\r)*?)shoes/$` should match; it takes into account the newlines. Edit: even shorter and better is `^This is test(?s:.*?)shoes/$` as suggested in the comments by @Wiktor.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Getting that ? as quantifier at right place was difficult part for me. Also I wrongly assumed Notepad++ will take care of newlines for me.

Comment: @msinfo Do not use `(.|\n|\r)*?` as it greatly decreases performance, use `.*?` and check *`.` matches newline*.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew. for additional info. This will be helpful, as actual data contains 20-25 MB sized files, with average line count of 3,00,000. And yes tried matching `.` for _newline_, it worked too.

Comment: @msinfo You may forget about options and just use `^This is test(?s:.*?)shoes/$` or `(?s)^This is test.*?shoes/$`.

Comment: Right, `^This is test(?s:.*?)shoes/$` looks short and readable.

Comment: Had forgotten about the \s metacharacter, and I agree it is the better choice.

Comment: What result do you expect if the text contains lines beginning with `This is test` two or more times before the `shoes/` line? It is required to delete the text, starting with the first occurrence or the last or somewhere in between?